# How to connect to MySQL database in Julia

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia having used R for the last few years and I am struggling with my first task which is connecting to my AWS MySQL database.

I have followed many online tutorials but I get the same message no matter what I do.

Everything was installed yesterday so it should all be the current version.

julia-version = Version 1.5.2

Here is the code:

```
Pkg.add(PackageSpec(url="https://github.com/JuliaComputing/MySQL.jl"))
Pkg.add(PackageSpec(url="https://github.com/JuliaDB/DBI.jl"))

using MySQL
con = MySQL.connect("ec2blah.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com", "name", "password", db = "database")
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
UndefVarError: connect not defined
getproperty(::Module, ::Symbol) at Base.jl:26
top-level scope at data_prep.jl:18
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://juliadatabases.github.io/MySQL.jl/stable/), you should probably do something like this:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("MySQL")       # No need for a full PackageSpec here
Pkg.add("DBInterface")

using MySQL
using DBInterface
conn = DBInterface.connect(MySQL.Connection, "ec2blah.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
                           "name", "password", db = "database")
```