# DBInterface.connect returns MySQL.Connection(disconnected)

Tags: mysql, julia

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database. In the [Documentation](https://juliadatabases.org/MySQL.jl/stable/#Getting-started-1)  its recommended to use `DBInterface.connect` with a Type `MySQL.Connection` Object. The Database im trying to connect to gets listed with the `mysql> SHOW DATABASES;` command so there should be no problem on the MySQL side of things.
For now I implemented:

```
module Database

using MySQL
using DBInterface

const HOST = "localhost"
const USER = "root"
const PASS = "#####"
const DB = "databank"
const CONN = DBInterface.connect(MySQL.Connection, HOST, USER, PASS, db=DB)

export CONN

disconnect() = DBInterface.close!(CONN)

# gets called for cleanup
atexit(disconnect)

end
```

But when I call `CONN` from the REPL I get:

```
julia> using Database

julia> CONN
MySQL.Connection(disconnected)

julia>
```

I already checked [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64277796/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database-in-julia) for answeres, but my implementation should be the same.

Later down the line I was hoping to use `DBInterface.execute(CONN, sql)` but I get the error `ERROR: mysql connection has been closed or disconnected`