# Julia : how can I connect to my AWS MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, julia

I set up a database on amazon rds, and im trying to connect to it in a Julia module with the MySql and DBInterface packages  :

```
using DBInterface
using MySQL

dbcon = DBInterface.connect(MySQL.Connection, "pgdb-1.cy6onqf2jyfs.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com", "***", "***", db = "pgdb-1")

end
```

I keep getting the following error, and i dont understand why ; I created the db un the aws console and passed parameters :

```
(2002): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'pgdb-1.cy6onqf2jyfs.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (115)
in top-level scope at pog/pog/src/logger/logger.jl:35
in  at MySQL/trL1u/src/MySQL.jl:288
in #connect#5 at MySQL/trL1u/src/MySQL.jl:288 
in Connection at MySQL/trL1u/src/MySQL.jl:25 
in  at MySQL/trL1u/src/MySQL.jl:34
in connect at MySQL/trL1u/src/api/capi.jl:12
```

I'm new to db so im wondering if there were prereqs other than adding MySQL in pkg repl and creating the db on AWS.
I tried to follow the accepted answer on this thread [How to connect to MySQL database in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64277796/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database-in-julia), but im still getting the error

Comment: Can you connect to this database through other means? Like regular mysql client?

Comment: Looks like a security group issue or no public IP for your database